# Why useEffect's dependency array's variable's size has to be constant between renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I was changing a state between renders and logging that value on every time the state changes via useEffect. I noticed my console is showing this error bellow:
[image of console showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pzQy.png).

I'm not understanding why is it that I'm getting this error. It would be very helpful if someone could explain why is my console showing this error.

Here's the code if it helps:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Item from "./Item";
import { Item as ItemType } from "../types";

const Content: React.FC = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Array<ItemType>>([
    { id: 1, checked: false, item: "Banana" },
    { id: 2, checked: false, item: "Potato" },
    { id: 3, checked: false, item: "Charger" },
  ]);

  const onItemChecked = (id: number) => {
    const _items = items.map((item) =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item
    );
    setItems(_items);
  };

  const onItemDeleted = (id: number) => {
    const _items = items.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    setItems(_items);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(items);
  }, items);

  return (
    <main>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <Item
            item={item}
            key={item.id}
            onItemChecked={onItemChecked}
            onItemDeleted={onItemDeleted}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

Comment: Because it's the dependency array? The name kind of tells you what it's for: any variable in the array whose value changes will cause the side effect code to rerun. Leave the array empty and now you've guaranteed the side effect code will only ever run once, because you told React that there "are dependencies", and then you gave it a list that will never change. The one rule is that the array _always_ has the same variables in the same places. And on a "posting to SO" node: [do not post pictures of text](/help/how-to-ask): [edit] your post and copy-paste the actual text in.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry, my question's title was not on point - but I edited that. I'm asking why is it that - the variable that is on the dependency array of useEffect, cannot change it's size as the error message is showing.

Comment: Except you're not passing "a dependency array containing a variable", you're just passing "the variable" on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useEffect` dependency array requires stable values between renders. Changing the array's reference triggers the effect. To log `items` when it changes, use an empty dependency array `[]` or compare the array contents using methods like `JSON.stringify`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(items);
}, [JSON.stringify(items)]);
```

if you want to include the items array in the dependency array and want the effect to run whenever the items array changes,

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(items);
}, [items.join(',')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(items);
  }, [items]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you update your code like below?
Your way to use `useState` is not correct.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Item from "./Item";
import { Item as ItemType } from "../types";

const Content: React.FC = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Array<ItemType>>([
    { id: 1, checked: false, item: "Banana" },
    { id: 2, checked: false, item: "Potato" },
    { id: 3, checked: false, item: "Charger" },
  ]);
  const onItemChecked = (id: number) => {
    setItems(_items => _items.map((item) =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item
    ));
  };
  const onItemDeleted = (id: number) => {
    setItems(_items => _items.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(items);
  }, [items]);
  return (
    <main>
      <ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Item
          item={item}
          key={item.id}
          onItemChecked={onItemChecked}
          onItemDeleted={onItemDeleted}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  </main>
  );
};
export default Content;
```